# How to write an Event member for an F# interface?

Tags: events, interface, f#

I am new to F#. In C#, I have an interface defined as:

```
public interface IMenuEvents
   {
       event Action SaveEvent;
       event EventHandler<ParagraphReadyEventArgs> ParagraphReadyEvent;

       ....
   }
```

where

```
public class ParagraphReadyEventArgs : System.EventArgs
    {
        public ParagraphReadyEventArgs(string paragraph_title)
        {
            ParagraphTitle = paragraph_title;
        }

        public string ParagraphTitle { get; }
    }
```

How is the interface IMenuEvents written in F# ?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/members/events

Comment: code examples at github: https://github.com/search?l=F%23&q=%3CCLIEvent%3E&type=Code (must be logged in i guess for code search)

Comment: @citykid I'm afraid I do not know how to transalate the references cited to implementation of the above code. :(  How is "action" incorporated into an F# event?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given declaration translates to

```ml
open System

type ParagraphReadyEventArgs(paragraphTitle: string) =
    inherit EventArgs()
    member val ParagraphTitle = paragraphTitle

type IMenuEvents =
    [<CLIEvent>]
    abstract member SaveEvent : IDelegateEvent<EventHandler>

    [<CLIEvent>]
    abstract member ParagraphReadyEvent : IDelegateEvent<EventHandler<ParagraphReadyEventArgs>>
```

Key difference is that `EventHandler` wrapped inside `IDelegateEvent<T>`

Behind the scenes you get same interface that you could get with C#. [Decompilation](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AbEAzAzgHwgAcYA7AAgGUBPXAFxgFsBYAKDbupPIAUBDKHwDmgogAsASjD4ATagFEAbmToBBKENwAKIgOGixAFQCWdDDBDl6UY6SEBKcgF425N+VtiYNuuSUr1TS17V3dGJmBvckU+DF49ET5xEzMYZ3JdQUTk03M2Di40gEkAWTIAV39SOlxnULcAbQAeAGEAGSKqugA+AF168j5gaz4wX3DGSKgqPmUu8ksigBEYcyE+Bi6mroAJPlIZcyhu/NZ3cmb2zuVqvoGhkbHyCan4rIMpWQUb30WVtY2MC2u32h28TX47ySkmkci6gVw3W6QA)

I don't understand why F# chose to make things that complicated yet. Hope somebody have an answer for this question

Few words about original design: It's recommended for all events to have type `EventHandler` or `EventHandler<TEventArgs>`, don't use custom event types. If you concern about memory allocation from `EventArgs`, then use `EventArgs.Empty` instead of `new EventArgs()`

Comment: @JLOPD Wow! I know SO does not want thanks, but I would never had been able to get events in F#. Thanks! It is much appreciated.